# Does Varnish cache not compatible with Redis?

Tags: magento2, varnish, redis

I choosed a VPS account to host my Magento 2 site and i asked support to help me install Varnish,Memcached,XCache and Redis and i got this answer:

"
Please note that not all of the services can be installed at the same time, because the services are not compatible with each other. In order to avoid any issues with your server I would like to suggest you the installation of Varnish and Memcached.
"

Im wondering wheter this information is correct or not because i read everywhere that top Magento optimization including Varnish and Redis at the same time.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The information is incorrect. All the software you mentioned can co-exist just fine on the same server.

However, note that you don't really need Memcached. If your intention to use it was for storing Magento PHP sessions - you can do the same just fine using Redis.